# Adding Home button in html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

In my webapplication I am trying to add home button in all the sub pages which on clicking will trigger `ActionResult Index()`
Any suggestions?

I have simply added a button in my Sub page DetailsForm. Which is next to the submit button. After user is done saving user can click on home button to directly got to the Index.cshtml. Avoiding any Browser back button.
Below code definitely doesn't work for me!

```
  <input type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" onclick="location.href='index.cshtml';" value="Home" />
```

Comment: You should use `<a>`.

Comment: Try <a href="/" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">Home</a>

Comment: Make it simple. `<a href="/">Home</a>`

Comment: Are you getting an error? You are trying to use a javascript button but we have no context information. What specifically is not working.

Comment: @DanielCopley    I tried   `<a href></a>`    too but its still not working. I keep getting   `resource cannot be found`  error. I feel its unable to load Index page back.

Comment: I think I know what you did. See edited answer below

Comment: Whats the edit?

Comment: Check the edit section of my answer below.

Comment: You do not navigate to `.cshtml` pages in MVC - you navigate to action methods in controllers  But just create a link using `@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", null, new { @class = "btn btn-lg btn-success" }` and its will be styled as a button because of the bootstrap classes.

Comment: @StephenMuecke works well for me .. Thanks :) But what i noticed is usually the home page is   `http://localhost:23943/Home/Index`   when I click on home button in sub page its routed back to   `http://localhost:23943`   seeing few of the styling missing too. Anything I am missing out?

Comment: The `Home/Index` is removed from the url because your using the default route (which specified the default controller as `Home` and the default action as `Index` which is what should happen. I cannot guess about your styling (ask a new question with the relevant details)

Comment: ok. Can you post your solution as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MVC, you navigate to action methods in controls, not to views so your `location.href='index.cshtml'` cannot work.

Use an `<a>` element to redirect (and style it to look like a button if that's what you want), for example

```
@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", null, new { @class = "btn btn-lg btn-success" }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can disable browser back button after saving using

```
history.pushState(null, null, document.title);
window.addEventListener('popstate', function () {
    history.pushState(null, null, document.title);
});
```

then you can go back to your home page using the button

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" onclick="goToHome()" value="Home" />
```

and you can add function in js as

```
 function goToHome () { 
    window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Index", "ControllerName")"
};
```

Comment: `location.href` seems enough for button click: `function goToHome () { window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Index", "ControllerName")" }`

Comment: Ajax calls never redirect!

Answer (score 0):

If you have CSS enabled use the `a` tag so style will be consistent and try

> `<a href="/link-to-index" class="button">Home</a>`

And in CSS make sure you have your button class designed.

```
a.button {
    -webkit-appearance: button;
    -moz-appearance: button;
    appearance: button;

    text-decoration: none;
    color: initial;
}
```

**EDIT**

From the error code you provided, it seems like you are most likely trying to use a library you haven't installed or installed correctly. I believe you are missing the Bootstrap Buttons library which can be found [here](https://getbootstrap.com). If you need help installing, instructions can be found in their [installation docs](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/download/).

Comment: I don't think that's an issue. My exact code is    `<a href="~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml"class="btn btn-lg btn-success">Home</a>'

Comment: Do you have the bootstrap buttons library?